# PySpark fill missing/wrong value with grouped mean

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a Spark dataframe with one missing and one wrong value.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, DoubleType, StructType, StructField
# fruit sales data
data = [Row(id='01', fruit='Apple', qty=5.0),
        Row(id='02', fruit='Apple', qty=1.0),
        Row(id='03', fruit='Apple', qty=None),
        Row(id='04', fruit='Pear', qty=6.0),
        Row(id='05', fruit='Pear', qty=2.0),
        Row(id='06', fruit='Mango', qty=6.0),
        Row(id='07', fruit='Mango', qty=-4.0),
        Row(id='08', fruit='Mango', qty=2.0)]
# create dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.show()
+-----+---+----+
|fruit| id| qty|
+-----+---+----+
|Apple| 01| 5.0|
|Apple| 02| 1.0|
|Apple| 03|null|
| Pear| 04| 6.0|
| Pear| 05| 2.0|
|Mango| 06| 6.0|
|Mango| 07|-4.0|
|Mango| 08| 2.0|
+-----+---+----+
```

Doing a fill by the entire column mean is straightforward. But how can I do a grouped mean? To illustrate, I would like the `null` in row3 to be replaced with the `mean(qty)` by `Apple` - in this case (5+1)/2=3. Similarly, the `-4.0` is a wrong value (no negative qty) in row 7 that I would like to replace with (6+2)/2=4

In pure Python I would do something like this:

```
def replace_with_grouped_mean(df, value, column, to_groupby):
    invalid_mask = (df[column] == value)
    # get the mean without the invalid value
    means_by_group = (df[~invalid_mask].groupby(to_groupby)[column].mean())
    # get an array of the means for all of the data
    means_array = means_by_group[df[to_groupby].values].values
    # assign the invalid values to means
    df.loc[invalid_mask, column] = means_array[invalid_mask]
    return df
```

And ultimately do:

```
x = replace_with_grouped_mean(df=df, value=-4, column='qty', to_groupby='fruit')
```

However, I am not quite sure how to achieve this in PySpark. Any help/pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Point of note:** When we do a group by, the rows having `Null` are ignored. If we have 3 rows with one of them having value `Null`, then average with be divided by 2, rather than 3 because 3rd value was `Null`. Key here is to use [Window()](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) function.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, col, when
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w = Window().partitionBy('fruit')

#Replace negative values of 'qty' with Null, as we don't want to consider them while averaging.
df = df.withColumn('qty',when(col('qty')<0,None).otherwise(col('qty')))
df = df.withColumn('qty',when(col('qty').isNull(),avg(col('qty')).over(w)).otherwise(col('qty')))
df.show()
+-----+---+---+
|fruit| id|qty|
+-----+---+---+
| Pear| 04|6.0|
| Pear| 05|2.0|
|Mango| 06|6.0|
|Mango| 07|4.0|
|Mango| 08|2.0|
|Apple| 01|5.0|
|Apple| 02|1.0|
|Apple| 03|3.0|
+-----+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks, Here I was thinking I would need something much more verbose. Will have to dig a little deeper to understand the `Window()` functionality.

Comment: Many people may use aggregate `.agg()` to have `mean` stored in another `dataframe` and then `join` the two `dataframes`, which implicitly is verbose and inefficient because of shuffles. `Windows()` is lot more efficient and succinct.

Comment: How to impute in case of categorical features with mode?