# Fill PySpark dataframe column's null values by groupby mean

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, group-by, null

I have a large PySpark dataframe that includes these two columns:

| highway | speed_kph |
| --- | --- |
| Road | 70 |
| Service | 30 |
| Road | null |
| Road | 70 |
| Service | null |

I'd like to fill the `null` values by the mean for that `highway` category.

I've tried creating another dataframe with groupBy, and ended up with this seconde one:

| highway | avg(speed_kph) |
| --- | --- |
| Road | 65 |
| Service | 30 |

But I don't know how to use this to fill in only the `null` values, and not losing the original values if they exist.

The expected result for the first table would be:

| highway | speed_kph |
| --- | --- |
| Road | 70 |
| Service | 30 |
| Road | ***65*** |
| Road | 70 |
| Service | ***30*** |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of `case` `when` and a window function partitioned by `highway` would solve it fairly easy.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

(df
    .withColumn('speed_kph', F
        .when(F.col('speed_kph').isNull(), F.mean('speed_kph').over(W.partitionBy('highway')))
        .otherwise(F.col('speed_kph'))
    )
    .show()
)

# Output
# +-------+---------+
# |highway|speed_kph|
# +-------+---------+
# |   Road|     70.0|
# |   Road|     70.0|
# |   Road|     70.0|
# |Service|     30.0|
# |Service|     30.0|
# +-------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks, that was quick ! About a minute before your answer I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54271504/pyspark-fill-missing-wrong-value-with-grouped-mean) that's basically the same.